# need plugin that allows to float from side of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Any help or guidance with this would be appreciated.

Thankyou in advance.

Im trying to create plugin that allows to float from side of the page
something like this

1. [image: it's in the left side of the page looks like this.. just like simple button..]

2.[image: then click it's floating like div.. :) sometimes it's contacts form, sometimes cart's (in e-shops), sometimes something else. :)]

if there is some kind of that plugin i would really happy to know its name or even better link :) 
what i need in it is color picking few.. :) and some other options to my one (editing) page.

Comment: also i found something similar.. but not enough for me.. :/  http://codebomber.com/jquery/slidepanel/

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for.

http://www.berriart.com/sidr/

Comment: yes! but still almost, but i think it will be good for me now.. :) thanks